# The method is undefined for the type (Array List) Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to implement interface methods in separate classes.
I created two interfaces to calculate Tax and PRSI for FullTimeEmployee and PartTimeEmployee. I implemented the interfaces and extended each class from a class called Employee. 
I created a new class to implement the methods the class is called Emplyee test I tried to group the FulltimeEmployee as an object into a array list.
I'm getting the method is undefined for this type when I try to implement the methods from it's class.
I spent quite a while trying to figure out the cause of the problem but I can't find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I included screen shots to highlight the issue. I know code is preferred, but I decided to show you all my classes as the problem can be lying in a other class.

```
import java.util.*;
 public class EmployeeTest  
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args){  

        ArrayList<FullTimeEmployee> empList = new ArrayList<FullTimeEmployee>();

        empList.add(new FullTimeEmployee("Adam", "Male","344667", 20000)); 

        empList.display();  

        empList.putHoursWorked(25);  
        empList.paySlip(); 



    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear. You are trying to call the method defined in `Employee` class on the `List` of `Employee`s.

You need to call the method on an instance of `FullTimeEmployee`:

```
FullTimeEmployee employee = new FullTimeEmployee("Adam", "Male","344667", 20000);
employee.putHoursWorked(25);
employee.paySlip();
employee.display();
```

Then of course you can do `empList.add(employee);`

You can also get the employee from the collection, like:

`empList.get(0)`

Comment: What do you mean by list interface? I passed the FullTimeEmployee into the Array List and it should the same as making an object with FullTimeEmployees. FulltimeEmployees has paySlip().

Comment: I also tries FullTimeEmployees a = new FullTimeEmployees and it gave back the same error

Comment: `empList` is a `List`, not a `FullTimeEmployee`. Adding an object to collection does not have any effect on which methods you can call on the collection. You have to retrieve the object from the collection and call the method on it, or do it before you add it to the collection. Please edit your original question and add code to it (as text, not images).

Comment: Thanks for the help I tried ... this and i still have the same issue ....
FullTimeEmployee a = new FullTimeEmployee("Adam", "Male","344667", 20000);
  ArrayList<FullTimeEmployee> empList = new ArrayList<FullTimeEmployee>();
  
  empList.add(new FullTimeEmployee("Adam", "Male","344667", 20000));